# ANTLR4 : lexing keywords that can be split over lines

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying to get a parser working for the IBM BMS language, and have hit a problem. In this language, certain things have to go in certain columns, and if they are too long to fit, then you can put a "continuation character" in column 72 to indicate that the content continues on the next line. Characters after column 72 should be ignored (they are essentially comments). So a line can look like this...

```
     DFHMDF POS=(3,39),LENGTH=9,INITIAL='VERSION :',ATTRB=(ASKIP,NO*00000250
           RM)                                                      00000260
```

...and it should parse the attribute as "ATTRB=(ASKIP,NORM)". I need the lexer to emit "NORM" as a single token. Note that this split can take place in any part of any keyword (and there are a lot of them).

I just wondered if anyone has got any ideas (or pointers to docs) as to the best way of approaching this problem using Antlr4. I have a separate lexer and parser grammar and I've had some limited success playing with the lexer, but it's getting very messy very quickly.

I'm no antlr4 expert, but everything I've been reading so far seems to suggest that this sort of thing is not easily done using this sort of parser (I'm beginning to wonder whether I need to hand craft something instead).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task to accomplish (parsing C header files) where continuation, stringizing etc. are common things and my approach was to implement a preprocessor which handled source lines first, e.g. it spliced lines where a line continuation character was found. With the result of this it was pretty straight forward to do normal parsing.

So I'd recommend to do such a line base preprocessing step, where your remove line end comments and after that splice split lines. Then feed this text to your parser, which can then be much simpler than what it must be if it was to handle also the line based tasks.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider that, but the AST being generated from the parse will be used for syntax highlighting, so I think removing code and splicing lines will make it a problem for maintaining locations of the tokens etc. Definitely worth thinking about though.